# SSIS Deployed Project validates Succesfully even with wrong Kingswaysoft Connection parameters

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2016, sql-job, kingswaysoft

I deployed a SSIS project with a pre-configured Kingswaysoft connection, a project connection.

I created different environments inside the SSISDB database, and I want to validate the project with every one of them.

I intentionally set wrong connection parameters to see the validation fail, but instead the result was OK.

Everything was put correctly, env variables linked to conn manager properties, etc.

How is it possible? Is the project validating with the first pre-configured connection set in design mode?

Only when I try to run a SQL Job with the wrong environment params it crashes, but I want to be able to trust the previous validation process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper way to set up this found here:

http://www.kingswaysoft.com/blog/2019/11/14/Parameterizing-CDSCRM-Connection-Manager

Answer (score 0):

Our KingswaySoft connection managers can be easily parameterized by using the connectionString, which is also the recommended approach. The below blog post, as you can see, explains the way to do that. The example shows the CDS/CRM connection manager, but this is applicable across all our components.
https://www.kingswaysoft.com/blog/2019/11/14/Parameterizing-CDSCRM-Connection-Manager

With this, you can quickly switch to another environment without the need to open your integration package in Visual Studio and change your connection settings manually. Instead, you can directly assign new values for your parameters before attempting to execute your SSIS package.

Let us know if there is anything else we can help you with and do not hesitate to reach out to our Support team directly.